# HTML, разница "_self/_blank"

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Прошу подробнее описать, как работает `_self` и `_blank` в html.

Интересует именно процесс загрузки страницы и javascript и разница в конечной выходной информации. 
 Почему при переходе по якорю на другую страницу с атрибутом **TARGET**(`_blank`), определенный javascript (fancybox) работает корректно, а при **TARGET**(`_self`), некорректно.

Модальное окно в первом случае открывается как надо, а во втором, модальное окно открывается на предыдущей странице, с которой был сделан переход по якорю(при нажатии кнопки браузера "назад", модальное окно открывается, но и открывается предыдущая страница). 
  Грешу на то, что при переходе с **TARGET**(`_self`), `javascript:'$(document)'` считает предыдущую страницу, а не текущую.

Как исправить проблему или сделать так, что бы **TARGET**(`_self`) вел себя точно так же, как и **TARGET**(`_blank`), но не в новом окне?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду **#** якорь. Да, почему-то браузеры начиная с ie5 или ie6 игнорируют якорь # (не запоминают историю). Максимум что можно пожалуй сделать - блокировать "уход" со страницы и самому следить за переходом между якорями - написав ф-цию перехода.

Comment: Вопрос надо задать не так, вас вижу не поняли. Вопрос звучит "почему при переходе через якорь # кнопка назад отправляет не назад, а на предыдущий сайт".

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на свой вопрос нашел в механизме кеширования страниц в браузере. Подробный ответ в статье [https://habrahabr.ru/post/225091/](http://habrahabr.ru/post/225091/).
Дело в работе самого браузера и события pageshow, pagehide и load. Если страница находится в кеше, то процесс загрузки проходит не полностью, а минует скрипты которые должны выполнятся при загрузке страницы, и событие load также не возникает, т.к. в большинстве случаев эта работа не нужна, и поэтому состояние страницы остается прежним.

Answer (score 0):

`_self` для того и предназначен, чтобы открывать ссылку в текущем окне, а `_blank` соответственно для открытия ссылки в новом окне.

Comment: Вопрос не в открытии окна в текущей вкладке или в новой, а в разнице загрузки страницы и javascript при target(“_self/_blank”).

Comment: да,действительно неверно понял

Comment: @Maks поменяйте текст вопроса. На вопрос разница "_self/_blank" вам и правда ответили верно).

Comment: Как сделать, что бы при переходе по якорю, страницы грузилась заново. А не как-то из кеша или из чего-то там) При _self ?

Comment: Подождите, якорь предполагает что страницу грузить не нужно, если у вас "новая" страница, и её надо загрузить - используйте вместо якоря # параметр "?name" или вообще укажите нужный параметр, например `?pg=2`

Comment: Я использую якорь для перехода на другую страницу и прокрутки на нужное место. То есть якорь находится к примеру на 1.html и ведет на страницу 2.html id="stage1". При этом мне нужна перезагрузка страницы 2.html для правильной работы javascript.